# How to drop all tables from the database with manage.py CLI in Django?

Tags: mysql, django, django-admin

How can I drop all tables from a database using manage.py and command line? Is there any way to do that executing manage.py with appropriate parameters so I can execute it from a .NET application?

Answer (score 146, accepted):

As far as I know there is no management command to drop all tables. If you don't mind hacking Python you can write your own custom command to do that. You may find the `sqlclear` option interesting. Documentation says that `./manage.py sqlclear` *Prints the DROP TABLE SQL statements for the given app name(s).*

*Update*:
Shamelessly appropriating [@Mike DeSimone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/207329/mike-desimone)'s comment below this answer to give a complete answer.

```
./manage.py sqlclear | ./manage.py dbshell
```

As of **django 1.9+** it's now

```
./manage.py sqlflush | ./manage.py dbshell
```

Comment: sqlclear "prints the drop statements" but how to execute them in single command line call

Comment: you need the app name like:
`./manage.py sqlclear myAppName | ./manage.py dbshell`

Comment: This doesn't work at all. sqlclear needs an app name. I'm on Django 1.8

Comment: Just be aware that sqlflush doesn't drop the tables, it truncates them. Also this operation probably won't work on your postgresql DB unless you add CASCADE keyword at the end of the truncate command generated by sqlflush.

Comment: No `./manage.py sqlclear`, for me it was `sqlflush`

Answer (score 54):

There's no native Django management command to drop all tables. Both `sqlclear` and `reset` require an app name.

However, you can install [Django Extensions](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions) which gives you `manage.py reset_db`, which does exactly what you want (and gives you access to [many more](http://django-extensions.readthedocs.org/en/latest/command_extensions.html) useful management commands).

Comment: I gave up trying and used this.

Comment: This worked for me, while none of the higher ranked answers did.

Comment: @AnujGupta also often  `manage.py reset_db` needs flag ` -c, --close-sessions`  to close database connections before dropping database (PostgreSQL only)

Comment: It is giving me Access denied for user '**MYUSERNAME**'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: For the record, `reset_db` is what I use for this.

Comment: The only one that worked for me.

Answer (score 37):

If you're using the South package to handle database migrations (highly recommended), then you could just use the `./manage.py migrate appname zero` command.

Otherwise, I'd recommend the `./manage.py dbshell` command, piping in SQL commands on standard input.

Comment: +1. Any non-trivial Django project should use South. And once you use South then migrating to Zero is a nice idiomatic way of dropping all tables.

Comment: Even trivial Django projects should consider South. Just to get people used to migrating databases, and so they don't learn bad habits like trying to dump, hack, and reload data by hand, or using the fixtures mechanism to migrate data.

Comment: I do use South, but I don't bother writing reverse migrations for every migration: not least data migrations. And I wouldn't do that just so I can use the zero option. Certainly a good way of testing that you /can/ reverse right back to zero, if that's important to you. Dropping all the tables seems reasonable to me.

Comment: Sure... and what if you have a non-trivial number of "apps"

Comment: Well, this question is ancient, South got subsumed into Django around 1.7, and I’ve used commands to migrate to zero with dozens of apps. `reset_db` (above) is my preferred tool for blowing everything away, but I’ve used migrate to get back to zero too. Django is pretty good with catching cross-app dependencies when creating migrations, so rolling something like `auth` back to zero gets almost everything.

Answer (score 35):

**`python manage.py migrate <app> zero`**

`sqlclear` was removed from 1.9.

Release notes mention that it is due to the introduction of migrations: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/releases/1.9/

Unfortunately I could not find a method that works on all apps at once, nor a built-in way to list all installed apps from the admin: [How to list all installed apps with manage.py in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21566919/django-listing-installed-apps)

Related: [How to reset migrations in Django 1.7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23755523/how-to-reset-migrations-in-django-1-7)

Comment: how about `sqlflush`?

Answer (score 14):

It is better to use `./manage.py sqlflush | ./manage.py dbshell` because sqlclear requires app to flush.

Answer (score 8):

simple(?) way to do it from python (on mysql):

```
from django.db import connection

cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('show tables;')
parts = ('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS %s;' % table for (table,) in cursor.fetchall())
sql = 'SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;\n' + '\n'.join(parts) + 'SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;\n'
connection.cursor().execute(sql)
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's a shell script I ended up piecing together to deal with this issue.  Hope it saves someone some time.

```
#!/bin/sh

drop() {
    echo "Droping all tables prefixed with $1_."
    echo
    echo "show tables" | ./manage.py dbshell |
    egrep "^$1_" | xargs -I "@@" echo "DROP TABLE @@;" |
    ./manage.py dbshell
    echo "Tables dropped."
    echo
}

cancel() {
    echo "Cancelling Table Drop."
    echo
}

if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    echo "Please specify a table prefix to drop."
else
    echo "Drop all tables with $1_ prefix?"
    select choice in drop cancel;do
        $choice $1
        break
    done
fi
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to completely wipe the database and resync it in the same go you need something like the following. I also combine adding test data in this command:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "main.settings") # Replace with your app name.

from django.db import connection
from django.core.management import call_command
from django.conf import settings
# If you're using postgres you can't use django's sql stuff for some reason that I
# can't remember. It has to do with that autocommit thing I think.
# import psychodb2 as db

def recreateDb():
    print("Wiping database")
    dbinfo = settings.DATABASES['default']

    # Postgres version
    #conn = db.connect(host=dbinfo['HOST'], user=dbinfo['USER'],
    #                 password=dbinfo['PASSWORD'], port=int(dbinfo['PORT'] or 5432))
    #conn.autocommit = True
    #cursor = conn.cursor()
    #cursor.execute("DROP DATABASE " + dbinfo['NAME'])
    #cursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE " + dbinfo['NAME'] + " WITH ENCODING 'UTF8'") # Default is UTF8, but can be changed so lets be sure.

    # Mysql version:
    print("Dropping and creating database " + dbinfo['NAME'])
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("DROP DATABASE " + dbinfo["NAME"] + "; CREATE DATABASE " + dbinfo["NAME"] + "; USE " + dbinfo["NAME"] + ";")
    print("Done")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    recreateDb();
    print("Syncing DB")
    call_command('syncdb', interactive=False)
    print("Adding test data")
    addTestData() # ...
```

It would be nice to be able to do `cursor.execute(call_command('sqlclear', 'main'))` but `call_command` prints the SQL to stdout rather than returning it as a string, and I can't work out the `sql_delete` code...

Comment: Nice the `USE DATABASE` I recommand you to create a django-recreate-db  package with a management command which will auto switch based on the settings to switch between SQLite3 et PostGresql.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example Makefile to do some nice things with multiple settings files:

```
test:
    python manage.py test --settings=my_project.test

db_drop:
    echo 'DROP DATABASE my_project_development;' | ./manage.py dbshell
    echo 'DROP DATABASE my_project_test;' | ./manage.py dbshell

db_create:
    echo 'CREATE DATABASE my_project_development;' | ./manage.py dbshell
    echo 'CREATE DATABASE my_project_test;' | ./manage.py dbshell

db_migrate:
    python manage.py migrate --settings=my_project.base
    python manage.py migrate --settings=my_project.test

db_reset: db_drop db_create db_migrate

.PHONY: test db_drop db_create db_migrate db_reset
```

Then you can do things like:

`$ make db_reset`

Answer (score 3):

This answer is for postgresql DB:

Run:

```
echo 'drop owned by **some_user**' | ./manage.py dbshell
```

NOTE: **some_user** is the name of the user you use to access the database, see settings.py file:

```
default_database = {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': 'somedbname',
    'USER': 'some_user',
    'PASSWORD': 'somepass',
    'HOST': 'postgresql',
    'PORT': '',
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using psql and have django-more 2.0.0 installed, you can do

`manage.py reset_schema`

Answer (score 2):

The command `./manage.py sqlclear` or `./manage.py sqlflush` seems to clear the table and not delete them, however if you want to delete the complete database try this : `manage.py flush`.

**Warning:** *this will delete your database completely and you will lose all your data, so if that not important go ahead and try it.*

Comment: No, this is incorrect. flush and sqlflush is the same, it removes all data, but doesnt drop tables. sqlflush displays the sql, but does not execute, flush executes it without displaying it.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to install [django-extensions](https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and use `python manage.py reset_db` command. It does exactly what you want.

Comment: Especially if you're using a docker container.

Answer (score 1):

Using Python to make a flushproject command, you use :

```
from django.db import connection
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(“DROP DATABASE %s;”, [connection.settings_dict['NAME']])
cursor.execute(“CREATE DATABASE %s;”, [connection.settings_dict['NAME']])
```

Comment: My question, is how to perform this if the database doesn't already exists ?

Comment: Sadly any further actions in the same script (e.g. syncdb) result in "No database selected" errors.

Comment: It did a command `flushdb` and after I launch another command. if you need it in another script, you might use `call_command`

Comment: I don't follow. I am already using `call_command`. You're saying I should do `call_command("flushdb")` before `call_command("syncdb")`?

Comment: Doesn't work. Same error. The error is "No database selected" so you can't execute *any* SQL. Found the solution: See my other answer.

Answer (score 1):

In django 4.1, the answer is to use `manage.py flush`. See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/django-admin/#flush).

Comment: it doesn't clear the table

Answer (score 0):

Here's a south migration version of @peter-g's answer. 
I often fiddle with raw sql, so this comes in handy as 0001_initial.py for any befuddled apps. It will only work on DBs that support `SHOW TABLES` (like mysql). Substitute something like `SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'public';` if you use PostgreSQL. Also, I often do this exact same thing for both the `forwards` and `backwards` migrations.

```
from south.db import db
from south.v2 import SchemaMigration
from django.db.utils import DatabaseError
from os import path
from logging import getLogger
logger = getLogger(__name__)


class Migration(SchemaMigration):

    def forwards(self, orm):

        app_name = path.basename(path.split(path.split(path.abspath(__file__))[0])[0])
        table_tuples = db.execute(r"SHOW TABLES;")

        for tt in table_tuples:
            table = tt[0]
            if not table.startswith(app_name + '_'):
                continue
            try:
                logger.warn('Deleting db table %s ...' % table)
                db.delete_table(table)
            except DatabaseError:
                from traceback import format_exc
                logger.error("Error running %s: \n %s" % (repr(self.forwards), format_exc()))
```

Coworker/cocoders would kill me if they knew I did this, though.

Answer (score 0):

There's an even simpler answer if you want to delete ALL your tables. You just go to your folder containing the database (which may be called mydatabase.db) and right-click the .db file and push "delete." Old fashioned way, sure-fire to work.

Comment: Only for sqlite databases though :-)

Answer (score 0):

Drops all tables and recreates them:

```
python manage.py sqlclear app1 app2 appN | sed -n "2,$p" | sed -n "$ !p" | sed "s/";/" CASCADE;/" | sed -e "1s/^/BEGIN;/" -e "$s/$/COMMIT;/" | python manage.py dbshell
python manage.py syncdb
```

**Explanation:**

`manage.py sqlclear` - "prints the DROP TABLE SQL statements for the given app name(s)"

`sed -n "2,$p"` - grabs all lines except first line

`sed -n "$ !p"` - grabs all lines except last line

`sed "s/";/" CASCADE;/"` - replaces all semicolons (;) with (CASCADE;)

`sed -e "1s/^/BEGIN;/" -e "$s/$/COMMIT;/"` - inserts (BEGIN;) as first text, inserts (COMMIT;) as last text

`manage.py dbshell` - "Runs the command-line client for the database engine specified in your ENGINE setting, with the connection parameters specified in your USER, PASSWORD, etc., settings"

`manage.py syncdb` - "Creates the database tables for all apps in INSTALLED_APPS whose tables have not already been created"

**Dependencies:**

- sed, to use on Windows, I installed UnxUtils: ([Download](http://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils/)) ([Installation Instructions](http://www.redantigua.com/unxutils-win.html))

---

**Credits:**

@Manoj Govindan and @Mike DeSimone for sqlclear piped to dbshell

@jpic for 'sed "s/";/" CASCADE;/"'

Answer (score 0):

A solution to remove **database** and **migrations** manually.

at the same level of `manage.py`, create `clean.py`

```py
import os


def recursor(dirpath):
    # print(dirpath)
    delfiles = []
    deldirs = []
    with os.scandir(dirpath) as l1:
        for e1 in l1:
            if not e1.is_file():
                with os.scandir(e1.path) as l2:
                    for e2 in l2:
                        if e2.name == 'migrations':
                            with os.scandir(e2.path) as l3:
                                for e3 in l3:
                                    if not e3.name == '__init__.py':
                                        print(e3.path)
                                        if e3.is_file():
                                            delfiles.append(e3.path)
                                        else:
                                            deldirs.append(e3.path)
                                            with os.scandir(e3.path) as l4:
                                                for e4 in l4:
                                                    delfiles.append(e4)
    yn = input('are you sure to delete all the files above?(y/n)')
    if yn == 'y':
        for dp in delfiles:
            os.remove(dp)
        for dp in deldirs:
            os.rmdir(dp)



recursor(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
```

delete `db.sqlite3` file and run `clean.py`

Answer (score -1):

use "python manage.py sqlflush" command in windows 10
for others type manage.py