# Reset SQLite database in Django

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I am trying to refactor a Django project. I renamed a couple apps and added a new one, as well as shuffled some models around. I want to clear my database and migrations and start fresh, but I am not sure how to accomplish this. Here's what I did:

```
rm -r myapp/migrations // I ran this for all my apps    
python manage.py flush
python manage.py makemigrations myapp // I ran this for all my apps
python manage.py migrate // This errors
```

I get an error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: table "myapp_mymodel" already exists
```

Can anyone tell me what I might be doing wrong?

EDIT: [What is the django command to delete all tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10605940/what-is-the-django-command-to-delete-all-tables) did not work.

Comment: Just delete the `.sqlite` file as well. It will destroy your data, but you don't seem to be bothered by that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the django command to delete all tables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10605940/what-is-the-django-command-to-delete-all-tables)

Comment: `flush` just drop the data, not the structure of your DB. You can see more here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10605940/what-is-the-django-command-to-delete-all-tables

Comment: You have to delete the migration files manually.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Delete database and delete migration files (`.py` and `.pyc`) in `migrations` directory of your app (don't delete `__init__.py` file). Then run `python manage.py makemigrations app` and `python manage.py migrate`.

Comment: which one should run first?  'python manage.py makemigrations app' or 'python manage.py migrate' ?

Comment: `python manage.py makemigrations app` obviously - you have to have something to migrate

Comment: Its correct to delete migration files and then run flush but deleting sqlite database file is wrong. This worked to me every time. If you are using other database, it will save you a lot of work and preparations.
1) delete all ".py" and ".pyc" files
2) >python manage.py flush               
                  type "yes" to confirm
3) >python manage.py makemigrations
4) >python manage.py migrate

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue, using Django 1.10, here is what I did, I deleted the database sqlite file, deleted the **pycache** folders inside each of the apps, deleted all files inside the migrations folder for each app , except the **init**.py file, and then ran `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`. Also note that because you deleted the database you will have to create a new superuser using `python manage.py createsuperuser`. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. This helped me

Answer (score 4):

For me, just

```
python manage.py flush
```

deleted old db contents, so i was able to create records anew in Django 2.1.4.

Don't forget to create new superuser:

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

Answer (score 1):

This may help you if you want to clear sqlite3 DB follow these steps.

1. Delete migrations files except **init**.py
2. Delete dbsqlit3 file
3. Then type `python/python3 manage.py migrate`
4. Then make changes in your models
5. Type `python/python3 manage.py makemigrations`
6. Type `python/python3 manage.py migrate`
7. Then you have to create new superuser by just typing  `python/python3 manage.py createsuperuser` . you should use new name not old user name

Answer (score 0):

**Do not delete your database file!**

Its correct to delete migration files and then run flush but deleting sqlite database file is wrong. This worked to me every time. If you are using other database, it will save you a lot of work and preparations.

1. delete all ".py" and ".pyc" files manually
2. python manage.py flush
   type "yes" to confirm
3. python manage.py makemigrations
4. python manage.py migrate