# How can i delete database table in django?

Tags: django, database, sql-delete

I changed my models and made migrations. Then i changed my models another one time and when try python manage.py migrate i get error:

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions, shop
Running migrations:
  Applying shop.0004_auto_20180128_1331...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/morilon/dj/intshop/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 83, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "/home/morilon/dj/intshop/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 301, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
sqlite3.OperationalError: table "shop_brand" already exists
```

So my question is - how can i delete table "shop_brand"???
I already tried `flush` and `sqlflush` but that only delete data from table but not actually table "shop_brand".

I use django 2.0.1 and python 3.6

Comment: Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37083445/reset-sqlite-database-in-django)

Comment: Just delete all files is an option but i want know how to delete only one tablet in database.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use the dbshell command

```
python manage.py dbshell
```

then while in the shell, depending on what database you are using, you type the command to show tables to identify the table you want to drop.

For instance, for sqlite, you would use

`.tables`

still in the shell, you can use SQL command to drop the table

```
DROP TABLE shop_brand;
```

Comment: I tried but CommandError: You appear not to have the 'sqlite3' program installed or on your path.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37287972/commanderror-you-appear-not-to-have-the-sqlite3-program-installed-or-on-your

Comment: or install sqlite3 `sudo apt-get install sqlite3`

Comment: Ok i will try. I just thought i can deal with it only with Django.

Comment: Why do I still those dropped tables in the admin site :(?

Comment: I CAN NOT restore the table after doing this by makemigrations or migrate