# Django sqlclear all app

Tags: database, django

My goal is to remove all tables in database(I'm using mySQL). Everytime I use sqlclear, it required app_names. How to remove all tables for each app?

Comment: i want to understand , you like to clear the data from your table, or you want to completely drop the tables

Comment: See relevant thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3414247/django-drop-all-tables-from-database

Comment: i hope you got a better answer with @alecxe thread

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no management command to drop all tables. You can write your own custom command to do that. Or you can use MySQL command to drop and create your database and then run `syncdb`.