# Python- running tests: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: python, django

I am starting to learn Python and Django, having never used them before. I'm following the tutorial at: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial05/ and have got as far as the 'Running Tests' section.

When I try to run the test using the command:

```
python manage.py test polls
```

the tutorial says that I should get an error that says:

> AssertionError: True is not False

However, when I run this, having followed what the tutorial says, the error that I'm getting says:

> django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1217, 'Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails')

My `models.py` file looks like this:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import datetime

from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

# Create your models here.
class Question(models.Model):
  question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
  def __str__(self):
    return self.question_text
  def was_published_recently(self):
    return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

class Choice(models.Model):
  question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
  def __str__(self):
    return self.choice_text
```

Can anyone explain why I'm getting a different error to the one the tutorial tells me to expect? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: what database you are using mysql,postgres,...?

Comment: I'm not sure... how can I check?

Comment: open `setting.py` in `DATABASES` section

Comment: I'm using mySQL

Comment: If you did not change the database config in your `settings.py` file, then your default database is an sqlite database, and you can see the file `db.sqlite3` in your project's base folder.

Comment: try to drop database and recreate it

Comment: also take alook  [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23453154/django-sqlclear-fails-to-delete-database-with-abstractuser-foreign-key-constra)

Comment: Would I drop and recreate the database from within the `was_published_recently(self)` method?