# django 1.7 migrations -- how do I clear all migrations and start over from scratch?

Tags: django, database-migration, django-south, django-1.7, django-migrations

So I'm rapidly iterating on a django app at the moment and I'm constantly adjusting models.py.  Over the course of a day or two of programming and testing I generate a couple dozen migration files.  Sometimes I really tear the schema apart and completely re-do it.  This causes the migration process to complain a great deal about defaults and null values and so on.  If possible, I would just like to scratch all the migration stuff and re-start the migrations now that I finally know what I'm doing.  My approach thus far has been the following:

1. delete everything in the migrations folder except for `__init__.py`.
2. drop into my PostgreSQL console and do: `DELETE FROM south_migrationhistory WHERE app_name='my_app';`
3. while at the PostgreSQL console, drop all of the tables associated with my_app.
4. re-run `./manage.py makemigrations my_app` - this generates a `0001_initial.py` file in my migrations folder.
5. run `./manage migrate my_app` - I expect this command to re-build all my tables, but instead it says:  "No migrations to apply."

What gives?

Also, is the `south_migrationhistory` database table still in play now that I've dumped South and have switched to Django 1.7?

Thanks.

Comment: Note that you can also delete the migration history from within Django (e.g. the shell): `from django.db.migrations.recorder import MigrationRecorder; MigrationRecorder.Migration.objects.filter(app=my_app).delete()`

Comment: duplicate/related: [How to reset migrations in Django 1.7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23755523/)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

So the step-by-step plan I outlined in my question does work, but instead of deleting rows from the `south_migrationhistory` database table, I had to delete rows from the `django_migrations` database table.

The command is:  `DELETE FROM django_migrations WHERE app='my_app'`

Once this is done, you will be able to re-run your migrations from scratch.

Comment: For future reference, I also had to delete everything inside the app's `migrations` folder.

Comment: @jon Doesn't it say the something like the relations already exist/ table already exists. because the tables are already there and migrate command tries to create them again

Answer (score 24):

I just wanted to put all the steps into a command format:

**NOTE:** The commands below are pretty destructive, it is a means to `start from scratch` as the OP asked.

After a comment from `mikeb` I thought to add this line:

PRE - **CHECK WHAT FILES YOU WOULD DELETE**

`find . -path "*migrations*" -name "*.py" -not -path "*__init__*"`

Then, adjust the command in step `1` to one that works for your dev environment.

1. remove all the migrations from all the apps:

```
find . -path "*migrations*" -name "*.py" -not -path "*__init__*" -exec rm {} \; # make sure to be in your projects path
```

2. recreate the whole database:

```
sudo -u postgres bash -c "psql -c \"DROP DATABASE rootedin;\""
sudo -u postgres bash -c "psql -c \"CREATE DATABASE rootedin;\""
sudo -u postgres bash -c "psql -c \"GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE rootedin to vagrant;\"" # vagrant is my current user
```

3. get your db up to date:

```
python3 manage.py makemigrations
python3 manage.py migrate
```

Comment: CAUTION:  Your find and delete statement will delete way more than you want to, potentially.  I ran just the find and discovered that it would have deleted a *bunch* of stuff in my virtualenv install, so I'd advise anyone reading this to beware of doing that.

Comment: That's a good note Mike, any suggestions on how to make it better? I don't use virtualenv so I can see why `*migrations*` can pick up a lot more.

Comment: Well, with virtualenv you can call your directory anything, so if your virtualenv install was in the `venv` directory you could add another `-not -path "venv/"` or something.  Perhaps easier and without having to know your virtualenv directory (or even if you're using it or not) you could use `-maxdepth 2`

Comment: If you don't want to be quite so destructive, say for example you want to reduce your migrations but not remove data from your models, you can skip #2 and then run `python3 manage.py migrate --fake` to apply the migrations without executing the SQL commands.