# Django falsely claims "There is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table"

Tags: python, django, django-1.7

If I add the following class to my model, all works fine on migration.

```
class BeursCheck(models.Model):
    order = models.IntegerField(default=None)
    painting = models.ForeignKey(Painting, related_name='beursCheck',primary_key=True)
```

However, if I add this field..

```
mturk_assignment = models.ForeignKey(
    'mturk.MtAssignment', null=True, blank=True,
    related_name='+', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, unique=True
)
```

It fails with error

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "mturk_mtassignment"
```

This field relates to MtAssignemnt, which *has* a unique key. [This related answered even says so.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42234330/django-error-on-migration-there-is-no-unique-constraint-matching-given-keys-fo)

```
class MtAssignment(MtModelBase):
     id = models.CharField(max_length=128, primary_key=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

try change to:

```
from mturk.models import MtAssigmnet

    mturk_assignment = models.ForeignKey(
        MtAssignment, null=True, blank=True,
        related_name='+', on_delete=models.SET_NULL
    )
```

Comment: the 'mturk.' refers to another app, where the MtAssignment is located.

Comment: @MitchellvanZuylen check сhanges in my answer

Comment: Regretfully, no changes.

Comment: @MitchellvanZuylen try to change related_name to 'mturk_assignments'

Comment: Did that to no avail