# Django makemigrations not working, how can i fix the dependencies?

Tags: python, django

I'm getting the error at the end of the trace back below. When I run 'python manage.py makemigrations'. I Get similar errors when I run it by 'python manage.py makemigrations accounts' and 'python manage.py makemigrations homedb'. If I run the accounts app, it says I'm missing a dependency in the accounts app and if I run the homedb app, it says I'm missing a dependency in the accounts app.

In an effort to fix this, I've deleted my migrations, many *pycache*_ items, and the database to no avail.

I also unstalled then reinstalled django.

I would be greatful for any help. This is a portion of my traceback:

```
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/PyKane/.virtualenvs/django23/lib/python3.9/site-packages/d
jango/core/management/base.py", line 373, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/PyKane/.virtualenvs/django23/lib/python3.9/site-packages/d
jango/core/management/base.py", line 417, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/PyKane/.virtualenvs/django23/lib/python3.9/site-packages/d
jango/core/management/base.py", line 90, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/PyKane/.virtualenvs/django23/lib/python3.9/site-packages/d
jango/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 88, in handle
    loader = MigrationLoader(None, ignore_no_migrations=True)
  File "/home/PyKane/.virtualenvs/django23/lib/python3.9/site-packages/d
jango/db/migrations/loader.py", line 53, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/home/PyKane/.virtualenvs/django23/lib/python3.9/site-packages/d
jango/db/migrations/loader.py", line 262, in build_graph
    self.graph.validate_consistency()
  File "/home/PyKane/.virtualenvs/django23/lib/python3.9/site-packages/d
jango/db/migrations/graph.py", line 195, in validate_consistency
    [n.raise_error() for n in self.node_map.values() if isinstance(n, Du
mmyNode)]
  File "/home/PyKane/.virtualenvs/django23/lib/python3.9/site-packages/d
jango/db/migrations/graph.py", line 195, in <listcomp>
    [n.raise_error() for n in self.node_map.values() if isinstance(n, Du
mmyNode)]
  File "/home/PyKane/.virtualenvs/django23/lib/python3.9/site-packages/d
jango/db/migrations/graph.py", line 58, in raise_error
    raise NodeNotFoundError(self.error_message, self.key, origin=self.or
igin)
django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError: Migration admin.0004_
alter_logentry_user dependencies reference nonexistent parent node ('hom
edb', '0005_account')
```

Comment: Have you tried faking the migrations with:
`python manage.py makemigrations` and then `python manage.py migrate --fake account`? Then running the migration as usual.

Comment: I just tried entering:
'python manage.py makemigrations --fake account'
I got the error that i have unrecognized areguments: --fake

then I ran makemigrations and migrate as usual, I received the same error

Comment: The exact order of operations is as follows: You can not fake `makemigrations` but you can do so with `migrations` only.
`python manage.py makemigrations`
`python manage.py migrate --fake account`
`python manage.py migrate`

Comment: I think there's progress? It's a different error which I think is good!

I'm getting the following when i complete those instructions then run 'python manage.py migrate' : 

```
 File "/home/PyKane/.virtualenvs/django23/lib/python3.9/site-packages/d
jango/db/migrations/loader.py", line 184, in check_key
    raise ValueError("Dependency on app with no migrations: %s" % key[0]
)
ValueError: Dependency on app with no migrations: accounts
```

Comment: Ok good, just replace `account` with `accounts` in the second command above.

Comment: bad news, we're back to the initial error : (

django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError: Migration admin.0006_
alter_logentry_user dependencies reference nonexistent parent node ('acc
ounts', '0001_initial')

if it matters, I'm using python anywhere

Comment: Do you have a space in the string 'acc ounts' in your command. If that is not the case, can you please mention at which command you get this error? Is it the last one?

Comment: I do not have a space, when i run the three commands you mentioned: 
1.a. python manage.py makemigrations
1.b. the error is django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError: Migration admin.0004_
alter_logentry_user dependencies reference nonexistent parent node ('hom
edb', '0005_account')
2a. python manage.py migrate --fake accounts
2.b. ValueError: Dependency on app with no migrations: accounts
3 python manage.py migrate

Comment: 3.b. django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError: Migration admin.0006_
alter_logentry_user dependencies reference nonexistent parent node ('acc
ounts', '0001_initial')

Comment: It seems like your migrations have dependencies in other apps such as admin. I would suggest deleting all of the migrations and start from scratch as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26283256/10256587).

Comment: awesome, thank you for  all your time! I will go through and delete the admin files