# Django deleted migrations directory

Tags: django, database-migration

In my project directory while I was trying to update my code I have accidentally remove the migrations folder of my app, now that I have modified the models and when I use `python manage.py makemigrations` I get the following message:

```
Operations to perform:
    Apply all migrations: app_label
Running migrations:
   No migrations to apply.
```

I have already run this before migrating `python manage.py makemigrations app_label`

Comment: Are you using version control? Can you just reset/checkout back to when you had the migrations?

Comment: @jonrsharpe unfortunately I'm on VPS and I still didn't get the time to install git server and I have migrations but for some reason when I place them up on server they give me the error that table exists

Comment: And that's why you make the time to install that first!

Comment: @jonrsharpe ok now what's your solution to solve the problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could just reset your migrations to before your initial `migrate` and start over.  This doesn't delete data in the database, but rather resets the tracking of your migrations.  If all of your databases are already migrated to the same level, then you can start over in your migration tracking.

There is a StackOverflow question here that already addresses it:

[How to reset migrations in Django 1.7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23755523/how-to-reset-migrations-in-django-1-7)

In short,

```
./manage.py migrate --fake <app-name> zero
```

This resets the tracking to prior to your initial migration.

And then,

```
./manage.py makemigrations <app-name>
./manage.py migrate <app-name>
```

Which recreates the initial migration and applies it.

As always, if your data is important, make a backup first.

Comment: I actually need the data in the database

Comment: I've updated my answer.  Resetting your migrations doesn't reset your database.

Comment: after running the command given above I got this message and nothing else actually happened `Running migrations:
  Rendering model states... DONE
  Unapplying app_label.0001_initial... OK`

Comment: This exception is now thrown relation "app_label_something" does not exist

Comment: You should now be able to proceed as you did when you initially started.

Comment: It would be helpful if you described what you ran to get that exception, and what `_something` is from.  Did you remake your migrations?

Comment: something is the name of another model related with foreignkey and yes I have removed migrations directory and ran makemigraions on the app again

Comment: problem is solved didn't run `makemigrations` and `migrate` after resetting migrations. Thank you

Comment: I've updated to make the process clearer.  'reset' to me means back to the beginning of time -- prior to initial migration.  That should be clearer now.

Comment: The order of execution may need to be changed as per the requirement. But it helps me a lot. Thanks much :)

Answer (score 13):

Just create new directory called migrations inside your app directory.
Then inside that folder create empty folder named `__pycache__` and a empty file named `__init__.py`. Then just make the migrations and migrate