# Integrity Error and Operational Error Django 1.6.6

Tags: django, django-models

I am just starting out to develop a Django Blog, and am following this youtube tutorial - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7rgph8en0Jc&spfreload=1

I am using Django 1.6.6.

1. Everytime I try to add Entry in Admin, I get this error. Thanks for your help!

> Environment:
>
> Django Version: 1.6.6
>      Python Version: 2.7.8
>      Installed Applications:
>      ('django.contrib.admin',
>        'django.contrib.auth',
>        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
>        'django.contrib.sessions',
>        'django.contrib.messages',
>        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
>        'niceblog',
>        'django_markdown')
>       Installed Middleware:
>       ('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
>        'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
>        'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
>        'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
>        'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
>        'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')
>
> ```
> Traceback:
> File "C:\Users\user\desktop\firstblog\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py"
> ```
>
> in get_response
>         112.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, >**callback_kwargs)
>       File "C:\Users\user\desktop\firstblog\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py"
>   in wrapper
>         450.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
>       File "C:\Users\user\desktop\firstblog\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py"
>   in _wrapped_view
>         99.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
>       File "C:\Users\user\desktop\firstblog\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py"
>   in _wrapped_view_func
>         52.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
>       File "C:\Users\user\desktop\firstblog\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py"
>   in inner
>         198.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
>       File "C:\Users\user\desktop\firstblog\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py"
>   in _wrapper
>         29.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
>       File "C:\Users\user\desktop\firstblog\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py"
>   in _wrapped_view
>         99.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
>       File "C:\Users\user\desktop\firstblog\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py"
>   in bound_func
>         25.                 return func(self, *args2, **kwargs2)
>       File "C:\Users\user\desktop\firstblog\lib\site-packages\django\db\transaction.py"
>   in inner
>         371.                 return func(*args, **kwargs)
>       File "C:\Users\user\desktop\firstblog\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py"
>   in add_view
>         1149.                 self.save_model(request, new_object, form, False)
>       File "C:\Users\user\desktop\firstblog\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py"
>   in save_model
>         878.         obj.save()
>       File "C:\Users\user\desktop\firstblog\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py"
>   in save
>         545.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
>       File "C:\Users\user\desktop\firstblog\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py"
>   in save_base
>         573.             updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, >update_fields)
>       File "C:\Users\user\desktop\firstblog\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py"
>   in _save_table
>         654.             result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
>       File "C:\Users\user\desktop\firstblog\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py"
>   in _do_insert
>         687.                                using=using, raw=raw)
>       File "C:\Users\user\desktop\firstblog\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py"
>   in _insert
>         232.         return insert_query(self.model, objs, fields, **kwargs)
>       File "C:\Users\user\desktop\firstblog\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py"
>   in insert_query
>         1514.     return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
>       File "C:\Users\user\desktop\firstblog\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py"
>   in execute_sql
>         903.             cursor.execute(sql, params)
>       File "C:\Users\user\desktop\firstblog\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\util.py"
>   in execute
>         69.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
>       File "C:\Users\user\desktop\firstblog\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\util.py"
>   in execute
>         53.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
>       File "C:\Users\user\desktop\firstblog\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py"
>   in **exit**
>         99.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
>       File "C:\Users\user\desktop\firstblog\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\util.py"
>   in execute
>         53.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
>       File "C:\Users\user\desktop\firstblog\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py"
>   in execute
>         452.         return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
>
> ```
> Exception Type: IntegrityError at /admin/niceblog/entry/add/
> Exception Value: niceblog_entry.slug may not be NULL
> ```

2. Everytime I try to edit Entry in Admin, it throws this error

> Environment:
>
> Django Version: 1.6.6 Python Version: 2.7.8 Installed Applications:
>   ('django.contrib.admin',  'django.contrib.auth', 
>   'django.contrib.contenttypes',  'django.contrib.sessions', 
>   'django.contrib.messages',  'django.contrib.staticfiles',  'niceblog',
>   'django_markdown') Installed Middleware:
>   ('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')
>
> Traceback: File
>   "C:\Users\user\desktop\firstblog\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py"
>   in get_response
>     112.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) File "C:\Users\user\desktop\firstblog\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py"
>   in wrapper
>     450.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs) File "C:\Users\user\desktop\firstblog\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py"
>   in _wrapped_view
>     99.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs) File "C:\Users\user\desktop\firstblog\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py"
>   in _wrapped_view_func
>     52.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs) File "C:\Users\user\desktop\firstblog\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py"
>   in inner
>     198.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs) File "C:\Users\user\desktop\firstblog\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py"
>   in _wrapper
>     29.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs) File "C:\Users\user\desktop\firstblog\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py"
>   in _wrapped_view
>     99.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs) File "C:\Users\user\desktop\firstblog\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py"
>   in bound_func
>     25.                 return func(self, *args2, **kwargs2) File "C:\Users\user\desktop\firstblog\lib\site-packages\django\db\transaction.py"
>   in inner
>     371.                 return func(*args, **kwargs) File "C:\Users\user\desktop\firstblog\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py"
>   in change_view
>     1255.             form = ModelForm(instance=obj) File "C:\Users\user\desktop\firstblog\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py"
>   in **init**
>     315.             object_data = model_to_dict(instance, opts.fields, opts.exclude) File
>   "C:\Users\user\desktop\firstblog\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py"
>   in model_to_dict
>     141.                 data[f.name] = list(f.value_from_object(instance).values_list('pk', flat=True)) File
>   "C:\Users\user\desktop\firstblog\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py"
>   in **iter**
>     96.         self._fetch_all() File "C:\Users\user\desktop\firstblog\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py"
>   in _fetch_all
>     857.             self._result_cache = list(self.iterator()) File "C:\Users\user\desktop\firstblog\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py"
>   in iterator
>     1068.             for row in self.query.get_compiler(self.db).results_iter(): File
>   "C:\Users\user\desktop\firstblog\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py"
>   in results_iter
>     713.         for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI): File "C:\Users\user\desktop\firstblog\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py"
>   in execute_sql
>     786.         cursor.execute(sql, params) File "C:\Users\user\desktop\firstblog\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\util.py"
>   in execute
>     69.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params) File
>   "C:\Users\user\desktop\firstblog\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\util.py"
>   in execute
>     53.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params) File "C:\Users\user\desktop\firstblog\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py"
>   in **exit**
>     99.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback) File
>   "C:\Users\user\desktop\firstblog\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\util.py"
>   in execute
>     53.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params) File "C:\Users\user\desktop\firstblog\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py"
>   in execute
>     452.         return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
>
> Exception Type: OperationalError at /admin/niceblog/entry/2/ Exception
>   Value: no such table: niceblog_entry_tags

models.py file --->

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.slug

class Entry(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body = models.TextField()
    publish = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Blog Entry"
        verbose_name_plural = "Blog Entries"
        ordering = ['-created']
```

admin.py file --->

```
class EntryAdmin(MarkdownModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("title", "created")

admin.site.register(Entry, EntryAdmin) 
admin.site.register(Tag)
```

Comment: You haven't synced/migrated your database properly.

Comment: i tried the usual python manage.py syncdb a couple of times. checked the table with python manage.py sql as well. somehow 'tag' is not appearing under the entry table.

Comment: @codemax Drop all your tables (if you are doing this for practice), delete all the migrations and create one initial migration. 
python manage.py schemamigration <app_name> --init

Comment: hi, i don't have schemamigration in my manage.py. but i dropped my table and deleted migrations

Comment: i found it by adding it in my settings.py file

Comment: I cleared the first stage, but everytime I apply python manage.py migrate my app, it tells me "FATAL ERROR - The following SQL query faied: CREATE TABLE "niceblog_tag" ("id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, "slug" varchar(200) NOT NULL UNIQUE) The rror was: table "niceblog_tag" already exists.

Comment: @codemax Drop the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess, Entry.tags was added after table creation.
If it's possible to upgrade django to 1.7 then you can use [built-in migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/migrations/). 
Firstable reset your app to actual db schema, i.e. remove tags field, then:

```
# Create initial migrations
$ python manage.py makemigrations your_app
# Migrate
$ python manage.py migrate your_app
# Add your tags field. Repeat
$ python manage.py makemigrations your_app
$ python manage.py migrate your_app
```

If you want to stay on django 1.6, use [South](https://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). It's pretty much the same:

```
# Create initial migrations
$ python manage.py schemamigration your_app intial --init
# Migrate
$ python manage.py migrate your_app --fake
# Add your tags field. Create migration
$ python manage.py schemamigration your_app add_tags --auto
$ python manage.py migrate your_app
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply. i downloaded south 1.0 but don't have schemamigration in manage.py... how do i get it?

Comment: i found it by adding it in my settings.py file

Comment: I cleared the first stage, but everytime I apply python manage.py migrate my app, it tells me "FATAL ERROR - The following SQL query faied: CREATE TABLE "niceblog_tag" ("id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, "slug" varchar(200) NOT NULL UNIQUE) The rror was: table "niceblog_tag" already exists.

Comment: I got to the last part with django 1.6 and South, but the error persists.

Comment: Looks like you should put Tags in the first stage to fake it migration. Because you already have it in your database.
Ok do next: open migration file, it's app/migrations/0002_add_tags.py. And comment db.create_table('app_tag', ...) then migrate again.
If it will pass migration, delete all migrations because they are mess now.

Comment: Here are good answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3414247/django-drop-all-tables-from-database
The easiest way is install [django extensions](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions)
Which gives yout reset_db:
$ python manage.py reset_db
Warning! It will destroy all your data!

Comment: thanks! how should i proceed with your suggested solution? do i restart the instructions as per given but change the 2nd part to python manage.py migrate tags --fake?

Comment: If you had dropped the database it's simple now: delete migrations dir, do **$ python manage.py syncdb** to sync schema, then **$ python manage.py schemamigration app init --init** and **$ python manage.py migrate app --fake**. Now you have your code, database and migrations are synced. That's it. Use south to add, delete or modify the database by creating and [applying schemas](https://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part1.html#changing-the-model).

Comment: thank you. i just did all that and niceblog_entry.slug may not be NULL still shows. not sure what else i can do

Comment: Are you trying save your tag with no slug?

Comment: i saved it with slug. if i didn't, the system would prompt me to. is there anywhere else in my codes i should take a look at? i only have the SlugField in models.py file though.

Comment: **niceblog_entry.slug** this means you didn't flush you db well. Because your model doesn't have that field and django doesn't warn you.
Just rename your old db to db_orig and let django create new one.
Make syncdb and everything should go fine.

Comment: it works!!! thank you very much! I think it worked after i deleted the database using python manage.py reset_db