# Easiest way to drop all tables to run syncdb in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-1.6

I keep making minor changes in my Django models. I don't care about the test data I keep adding, I just want to drop all tables (models) so I can run `syncdb` again. `manage.py flush` doesn't delete table schema, it just removes data.

Is there a quicker function in Django 1.6 to drop all tables?

Comment: You can use migrations - there is no need to remove all tables on each change.

Comment: If you don't care about the tables, it might be quickest to drop the entire database and recreate it. How to do this will depend on which database you are using.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django drop all tables from database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3414247/django-drop-all-tables-from-database)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Django 1.6 is an unsupported Django version https://www.djangoproject.com/download/#supported-versions

you can see that Django 1.6 was supported until April 2015. So try to migrate to 1.8 LTS or 1.9 now and have migrations in your Django project or integrate South in your old Django app to have migrations http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html

2) No there is not a quicker function in Django 1.6 (django-admin/manage.py command) that drop all tables. The more closer thing in this old versions is:

`manage.py sqlclear appname`

and put the output in your sql shell, maybe can work with pipe.

`manage py sqlclear appname | manage.py dbshell`

at least with MySQL works well.